# Dividing each row of a dataframe matrix by a vector with a shorter length in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe matrix 'd' I am working with, first column is time and the remaining 5 columns contain numerical values:

```
structure(c("2016-01-01 00:00:00", "2016-01-01 01:00:00", "2016-01-01 02:00:00", 
"206.000", "208.000", "208.500", "246.000", "246.000", "242.000", 
" 50.000", " 51.000", " 51.000", "207.500", "207.500", "209.000", 
NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(3L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("timestamp", 
"Crow_education_Omer", "Crow_education_Keisha", "Crow_education_Kate", 
"Crow_education_Winston", "Crow_education_Marlin")))
```

I would like to divide columns 2 to 6 of 'd' by a vector 'crow_sqm'

```
crow_sqm <- c(11857.4, 14173.2, 6320.2, 8659.1, 7561.4)
```

to get

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00     206.000   123.000   10.000    207.500   NA
2016-01-02 00:00:00     206.000   123.000   10.000    207.500   NA
2016-01-03 00:00:00     206.000   123.000   10.000    207.500   NA
```

Previously I converted the dataframe 'd' to a matrix using as.matrix(d) and deleted the first column of d. When I try to divide d/crow_sqm, I get the following error:

Error in d/crow_sqm : non-numeric argument to binary operator

'd' is currently shown under data and 'crow_sqm' is shown under values. Not sure if the error is from the NA values or something else. Can anyone advise?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sweep`.

```
sweep(type.convert(d[, -1]), 2, crow_sqm, `/`)

#     Crow_education_Omer Crow_education_Keisha Crow_education_Kate Crow_education_Winston
#[1,]               206.0                   123                10.0                  207.5
#[2,]               208.0                   123                10.2                  207.5
#[3,]               208.5                   121                10.2                  209.0

#     Crow_education_Marlin
#[1,]                    NA
#[2,]                    NA
#[3,]                    NA
```

Or with transpose.

```
t(t(type.convert(d[, -1]))/crow_sqm)
```

The data is a matrix and matrix can have data of only one type. The 1st column cannot be represented as number hence all the values in the matrix turns to be of type character. `-1` is used to drop 1st column in the matrix and `type.convert` is used to change values from character to numeric for all the columns.

Comment: I tried using sweep with the following after renaming 'c' as 'd': 
e = sweep(d, 2, crow_sqm, '/') 

but got the following error:

Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...) :  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Not sure what the [-1] does? Would you be able to explain as well? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Do you have dataframe or matrix? What does `class(d)` return. 2. The error suggests that your columns are not numeric. It would be helpful if you provide a reproducible example to avoid this confusion. Edit your post to include `dput(d)`. 3) Does this work? `sweep(type.convert(d[, -1]), 2, crow_sqm, \`/\`)`

Comment: Thanks. class(d) returns "matrix" "array". The sweep function worked. Would you be able to explain why it didn't work before and what the type.convert() is doing? Thank you.

Comment: I edited the answer to include some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

With a little tweak you can do it without converting to matrix

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
cbind(df["timestamp"], df[,-1] %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  purrr::map2_df(crow_sqm, ~ .x/.y))

            timestamp Crow_education_Omer Crow_education_Keisha Crow_education_Kate Crow_education_Winston Crow_education_Marlin
1 2016-01-01 00:00:00          0.01737312            0.01735670         0.007911142             0.02396323                    NA
2 2016-01-01 00:00:00          0.01754179            0.01735670         0.008069365             0.02396323                    NA
3 2016-01-01 02:00:00          0.01758396            0.01707448         0.008069365             0.02413646                    NA
```

You need not `mutate(across..` if you are working with your df directly, as the data type may have changed while converting it to matrix

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` to make it

```
df[-1] <- Map("/", df[-1], crow_sqm)
```

such that

```
> df
            timestamp Crow_education_Omer Crow_education_Keisha
1 2016-01-01 00:00:00          0.01737312            0.01735670
2 2016-01-01 01:00:00          0.01754179            0.01735670
3 2016-01-01 02:00:00          0.01758396            0.01707448
  Crow_education_Kate Crow_education_Winston Crow_education_Marlin
1         0.007911142             0.02396323                    NA
2         0.008069365             0.02396323                    NA
3         0.008069365             0.02413646                    NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(timestamp = c("2016-01-01 00:00:00", "2016-01-01 01:00:00",
"2016-01-01 02:00:00"), Crow_education_Omer = c(206, 208, 208.5
), Crow_education_Keisha = c(246, 246, 242), Crow_education_Kate = c(50,
51, 51), Crow_education_Winston = c(207.5, 207.5, 209), Crow_education_Marlin = c(NA,
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```